# Python merge two dictionaries and output them to csv file

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2 dictionaries that look like that :

```
subjects = {'aaa' : 1,
           'bbb' : 1,
           'ccc': 1}

objects = {'aaa' : 1,
           'bbb' : 1,
           'ccc': 1}
```

I want to output them to a csv file that will have the string, times as a subject and times as an object.

For the 2 dictionaries I want the csv file to look like that :

```
aaa,1,1

bbb,1,1

ccc,1,1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `pandas`, it's really useful for these kind of tasks.

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> subjects = {'aaa' : 1, 'bbb' : 1, 'ccc': 1}
>>> objects = {'aaa' : 1, 'bbb' : 1, 'ccc': 1}
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame([subjects]).T
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame([objects]).T
>>> pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1).to_csv('./out.csv', header=False)

aaa,1,1
bbb,1,1
ccc,1,1
```

Or you can do the same without pandas:

```py
subjects = {'aaa' : 1, 'bbb' : 1, 'ccc': 1}
objects = {'aaa' : 1, 'bbb' : 1, 'ccc': 1}
with open('./out.csv','w') as f:
    for k in subjects:
        f.write(f'{k},{subjects[k]},{objects[k]}\n')
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without pandas? I'm writing my code in cmd and there is no panda and I can't install it there

Comment: sure, here's a version without pandas